# Is there a square matrix $\mathbf{A}$ such that $A^4=-I$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Is there an n $\times$ n $\mathbf{A}$ such that $\mathbf{A}^4=-I$?

I can't see how to prove that this is not possible. One obvious observation is that $n$ has to be even by considering the determinant. I tried some particular cases, such as constructing 2x2 matrices that satisfy the condition. Since
$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}^2 = -\mathbf{I}$. I tried to find $\mathbf{A}^2=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$, but I can show there is no such $\mathbf{A}$. Therefore I want to seek help here. Thanks very much.

P.S. I haven't been taught anything about the diagonalization of a matrix yet.

Comment: Is $n$ arbitary ? Must the entries be real ?

Comment: Actually, if $n$ is odd you can just take $A=-\operatorname{Id}$. Why do you claim that $n$ has to be even?

Comment: @Peter Yes, $n$ is arbitrary and the entries must be real.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos  I thought that $\det(-I) = -1$ if n is odd but $\det(A^4) = \det(A)^4$ has to be non-negative.

Comment: A $2\times 2$ example is rotation by $\pi/4$ on a plane $A=\begin{pmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt2}&-\frac1{\sqrt2}\\\frac1{\sqrt2}&\frac1{\sqrt2}\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $(-I_n)^4 = I_n$ whatever is $n$, so this won't work

Comment: Sorry. I was thinking about $A^n$ rather than $A^4$.

Answer (score 6):

I tried random matrices with PARI/GP and actually found an example doing the job with size $4\times 4$ : $$\pmatrix{1&1&-1&-1\\0&0&1&-1\\1&1&-1&0\\0&1&0&0}$$

Comment: Or simpler: take the companion matrix of $p(x)=x^4+1$ :)

Comment: @user10354138 I thought about this idea. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with complex numbers?  Can you solve $z^4 = -1$?

Next, do you know that there is a subring of the $2 \times 2$ real matrices is isomorphic to the complex numbers?

This should give you a $2 \times 2$ solution.  This can be easily expanded to larger sizes.